# Comparing dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time

One of the fields in a table contains a date which type is `DATETIME`. Now I want to check, if there are rows in the table where `date > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`. This returns nothing. I have inserted data in the table within the five minutes when I tried to run the code above, but as already said, nothing appears.

It seems the comparison isn't valid. How do I check, if there is data in the table inserted in the last five minutes?

Comment: You sure your data is correct? Works for me, while I do recommend adding parentheses to your left expression. You should also avoid using *keywords* as column names.

Comment: I think too it should work, but it seems something is wrong. In the database I have a row with column `date` set to `2012-11-30 22:38:41` and when I tried this the time was `2012-11-30 22:39:03`.

Comment: Lol, my bad. I had accidentally added `DATE(date) > ...`. I tried it with interval of days and I realized that. Thanks!

Comment: You should delete your question or answer it yourself instead of marking an answer that is not technically correct.

Comment: Good idea, though I can't delete because dtbarne has answered this question.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 MINUTE);
```

Also, make sure you have your timezones straight.

Comment: - `NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` is shorthand. They both do the same thing.

Comment: Why not `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`?

Comment: Technically this was not the answer. Marking it so may cause confusion for future readers.